# Parameter must be an array and Internet Server 500 error

Tags: server, apache2, phpmyadmin

I'm currently working with a database and I keep running into a similar problem. I've looked at many of the similar forums and it's answers but wasn't able to fix it.

Ubuntu 18.04
Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)
PHP version: 7.2.15-0ubuntu0.18.04.1
PMA: 4.6.6deb5

Every time I click on a database Table, i always get the following error.

```
count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable
```

I did configure the file (looked at many forums) but when i changed the following lines, this is what i get.

```
error in processing request error code 500 error text internal server error
```

I changed the following lines:

```
(count($analyzed_sql_results['select_expr'] == 1)
```

TO

```
((count($analyzed_sql_results['select_expr']) == 1)
```

Please help me out. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This were my settings:

Ubuntu 18.04
PHP 7.2
PMA 4.4.6

The reason why i was getting all those errors were becase phpMyAdmin is not compitable with the latest version of PHP/MySQL hence an update was needed. So I went back to the terminal and got the latest version of PMA (4.8). It's up and running without any problems.

Comment: Hi, Jainam Patel, how did you get PMA 4.8? Could you write down the steps or share some manual?

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced the same problem, with PhpMyAdmin 4.6.6 on Ubuntu 18.04, and found [the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49483740/6543935), provided by [Jacky Nguyen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9550466/jacky-nguyen), on Stack Overflow:

> Edit file `/usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/sql.lib.php`:
>
> ```
> sudo nano /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/sql.lib.php
> ```
>
> Replace: `count($analyzed_sql_results['select_expr'] == 1)`
>
> With:  `(count($analyzed_sql_results['select_expr']) == 1)`
>
> Restart the server apache:
>
> ```
> sudo service apache2 restart
> ```

Comment: That was my default line. It keeps giving me the same error.

Comment: If i do configure it, then it would give me the "internal 500 error".

Comment: @JainamPatel: Strange, I just checked my PMA instance and it works well with this fix. The only idea I have is to try to flush your browser's cache.

Comment: I have cleared cache and cookies. Still nothing.